# General solution of this very simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking to confirm that the general solution for

$$\frac{\delta ^{2}u(\omega ,t)}{\delta ^{2}t} + c^{2}\omega ^{2}u(\omega, t) = 0$$ is indeed 
$$A(\omega)e^{c\omega t}\cos(c\omega t) + B(\omega)e^{-c\omega t}\sin(c\omega t)$$
The solutions on my text on Fourier transform is showing a different solution:

$$A(\omega)e^{ic\omega t} + B(\omega)e^{-ic\omega t}$$

Comment: I'm a little rusty on my DE but I think there shouldn't be an exponential term on the second line.

Comment: Everything that can be written in the first form can be written in terms of the second, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Since the real part of the solutions of the auxiliary quadratic is zero, it should be $$A(\omega)\cos(c\omega t) + B(\omega)\sin(c\omega t)$$
this is equivalent to the solution in your text but for different $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0):

Those are the same solutions!  By picking the right coefficients you can make them agree. Recall that both sine and cosine can be written with the exponential function in the complex setting.

Comment: The caveat is to pick the right coefficients but if the coefficients were not stated nor worked out, how could one ever say they are in agreement?

Comment: The idea is that the set of functions described by the first expression is equal to the set of functions described by the second. The goal is to describe all solutions. Each solution can be written either way.

Comment: These coefficients are just arbitrary constants without the initial condition.

Comment: @ZachStone Do you have a link to this? It's amazing how forgetful humans can be.

Comment: Here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities. Check out the section on "relation to the complex exponential".